# Form required field in django model forms

Tags: python, django

i have a model form however I'm struggling to set one field as required without changing the model itself. Is there a way of making the location field mandatory without changing models.py when the user submits the form?

modelys.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, choices=GENDER, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    home_university = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

my forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "location",
            "picture",
            "bio",
            "gender",
            "home_university",
            ]
```

and my views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_complete(request):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect("home")
    context = {
        "form": form,

                }
    return render(request, "profiles/profile_complete.html", context)
```

Comment: You can redefine field on forms.py file. If you define the blank=True for that field, Django change required False by default. But you can define the field again in ProfileForm class, above the class Meta line. (Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use these options:

1 - **init** function:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Making location required
        self.fields['location'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "location",
            "picture",
            "bio",
            "gender",
            "home_university",
            ]
```

2 - by redefining the field:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "location",
            "picture",
            "bio",
            "gender",
            "home_university",
            ]
```

In your case there would be no problem because your model is `null=True` and you're setting the field to required but if you do this for some other model field with `null=False` and override the field in ModelForm to `required=False`, then you have to provide a value in your form or view before you save it to database otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: No problem ;) @caldf

Answer (score 1):

For general knowledge, I had the same problem, I solve it as follow, in **Django 4.0** you can add "required" in widgets in the Meta class

so your forms.py will be:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        "location",
        "picture",
        "bio",
        "gender",
        "home_university",
        ]
    widget = {
        "location":forms.TextInput(attrs={"required": True})
        }
```